# Borrar una fila de un datagridview, mediante el ROWINDEX

Tags: vb.net

les planteo el siguiente problema. Tengo un datagridview con 3 registros, estos los agrego manualmente, no esta enlazado, hago dos ciclos en el primero recupero el rowindex de los registros marcados para borrar estos los lleno a una variable de tipo arreglo, hasta aqui bien segun yo.

Ahora creo un segundo ciclo para borrar estos registro, que vienen en el arreglo, en resumen mi problema es implementar el borrado con el array que llene, he tratado de varias formas. les dejo mi codigo en dos bloques.

```
Dim aoEliminar() As Integer
'Contar el numero total de filas que estan en el dgv
For Each aoRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvCuentaTotal.Rows
    'Marcar los registros a borrar unicamente
    If Convert.ToBoolean(aoRow.Cells("Traspasar").Value) Then
        anEliminar += 1
        'ReDim Preserve aoEliminar(anEliminar)
        ReDim aoEliminar(aoRow.Index)
    End If
Next

'Segundo ciclo eliminar el indice seleccionado
For Each aoRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvCuentaTotal.Rows
    dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Remove(dgvCuentaTotal.CurrentRow)
        '(aoEliminar(aoRow.Index))
    dgvCuentaTotal.Refresh()
Next
```

Esto lo hice asi por que si lo borro directamente, se pierde el borrar y no recorre toda la tabla y un amigo me dio esta suferencia, leer los registros a borrar, luego en un segundo ciclo, eliminar los seleccionado.

gracias

Comment: Creo que te estas complicando un poco. Supongo que haces dos ciclos porque no puedes eliminar las filas dentro de un bloque `For Each`. Lo que yo haría es usar un `For` descendente, acceder por indice a las filas y eliminar las que cumplan la condición.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como comenta @Pikoh la solución más rápida sería recorrer el grid de forma descendente e ir eliminando las filas que cumplan la condición.

```
for i as integer = dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Count - 1 to 0 step -1
    If Convert.ToBoolean(dgvCuentaTotal.Rows(i).Cells("Traspasar").Value) Then
        dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Remove(dgvCuentaTotal.Rows(i))
    End if
next
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, a esto exactamente me refería.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pikoh y Roger Toma, quedo al 100%. Saludos